# Devise and AJAX: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity after sign in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, devise

Heyo,

I'm using Rails 4 and Devise, and have overridden the Devise controllers to allow AJAX sign ins and registration. It's a one-page app. When a user registers, they can perform all necessary AJAX POSTs. When they sign IN, however, they can't - I get "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity" on the server side. This happens until I refresh the page - then the CSRF token updates and I can POST normally.

Any idea why this just happens after a registered user signs in, and not on after registration or a page refresh? Here's the code in my controllers:

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    resource = warden.authenticate!(:scope => resource_name, :recall => "#{controller_path}#failure")
    sign_in_and_redirect(resource_name, resource)
  end

  def sign_in_and_redirect(resource_or_scope, resource=nil)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    resource ||= resource_or_scope
    sign_in(scope, resource) unless warden.user(scope) == resource
    @badge = resource.badge
    return render 'signin.js.erb'
  end

  def failure
    return render :json => {:success => false, :errors => ["Login failed."]}
  end

  def destroy
    redirect_path = '/labs'
    signed_out = (Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name))    
    yield resource if block_given?

    # We actually need to hardcode this as Rails default responder doesn't
    # support returning empty response on GET request
    respond_to do |format|
      format.all { head :no_content }
      format.any(*navigational_formats) { redirect_to redirect_path }
    end
  end
end
```

And my Registration controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        return render 'signup.js.erb'
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        return render :json => {:success => true}
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      return render :json => {:success => false}
    end
  end

  # Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own
  # RegistrationsController.
  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  end

end
```

Annnd the AJAX post in question:

```
$(document).on('click', '.project_item', function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/hammer/thing_toggle',
      data: 'id=' + $(this).data('id')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. It's kind of hacky, but it does the trick.

When a user signs in, I load some HTML that contains a new <%= csrf_meta_tags %> element, and force the AJAX requests to use that new token:

```
$(document).on('click', '.project_item', function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').last().attr('content'))},
      url: '/hammer/thing_toggle',
      data: 'id=' + $(this).data('id')
    });
});
```

It's strange that the csrf_meta_tags token value changes when signing in VIA ajax, but not when I register a user VIA ajax. Strange, indeed... If anyone has any insight into why this is, it'd be appreciated!

Comment: If you're using devise. check this commit https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/747751a2 they cleared csrf_token after sign in.

Answer (score 0):

I figured when signing in with Devise using AJAX, the csrf_token stored in the session gets cleared. I had to write an API to generate a new csrf_token after I sign in. Call it and update my csrf_token in the html header.

My api_controller.rb:

```
class ApiController < ApplicationController
  
  def reload_csrf 
    render json: { csrf: form_authenticity_token }, status: :ok
  end

end
```

My AJAX call after sign_in:

```js
// Get and set new csrf token after the new session
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/reload_csrf.json",
    success: function (response) {
        $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content', response.csrf);
    }
});
```

Then all my form submissions will use the new and valid csrf token.

Comment: This is a nice way of doing it, but it also exposes a security vulnerability. If you can get the updated CSRF using a simple GET call then what is the point of the CSRF in the first place?

Answer (score -1):

just in case anyone comes across this again, the above answer is correct.

here [is the link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/547e18e24e7141d65357d97210bcb342161ca2b7/lib/generators/templates/devise.rb#L86) from devise explaining this. we use form_authenticity_token.to_s in our controller to send it back via ajax.